# Does $\frac{(1+Z_1+...+Z_X)}{X}$ first-order stochastically dominate $\frac{(0+Z_1+...+Z_Y)}{Y}$?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $Z_i$ is i.i.d. and follows Bernoulli distribution of success probability $p$.

Then, does $\frac{(1+Z_1+...+Z_X)}{X}$ first-order stochastically dominate $\frac{(0+Z_1+...+Z_Y)}{Y}$? where $X$ and $Y$ are both positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $X=3,Y=1,p=1/9$. Then 
$$
P\left(\frac{1+Z_1+Z_2+Z_3}{3}> \frac23\right)=P(Z_1+Z_2+Z_3>1)=3(8/9)(1/9)^2+(1/9)^3\approx 0.034\\
P\left(\frac{0+Z_1}{1}> \frac23\right)=P(Z_1=1)=1/9\approx 0.11
$$
You can generate more counterexamples with this code: https://repl.it/@mearnest/Stochastic-Domination.